# Time complexity for quantum computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, computational-physics, quantum-computer

Is there any systematic way to obtain a quantum algorithm's time complexity knowing the classical time complexity of the same algorithm type running for bits instead of qubits?
For example, we know that the Grover algorithm is associated with $\sqrt{N}$ complexity while the classical counterpart is with N.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is "no" in general because it was a big deal to discover that prime factoring could be done faster on quantum computers than on classical computers. Furthermore, if there were a systematic way to do what you say, we would know whether or not quantum computing were strictly more powerful than classical computing, which we seem to not know.

Comment: Seems like that should be an answer @DanielSank

Comment: You you mean for specific algorithms, or for the optimal way to solve a given problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the answer is "no" in general because it was a big deal to discover that prime factoring could be done faster on quantum computers than on classical computers. Furthermore, if there were a systematic way to do what you say, we would know whether or not quantum computing were strictly more powerful than classical computing, which we seem to not know.